# Transcription of an interview of Kazuya Kato

Tags: soft-question, translation

On [this](http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/video/vgbook/idx_vguest2006.html) page, the interview is [here](http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/video/vgbook/2006/0602kato_L.ram). Can someone provide an English translation?

Comment: Fixed the links and added the translation tag.  Not sure how appropriate this question is for this site, though.  Transcribing 10 minutes of spoken Japanese is not an insignificant task.  The relevant interview is the one on the 2 June 2006 (or 2006年6月2日, in the page).

Comment: pmoduli asked if it was appropriate on meta a while back and the consensus was yes: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/407/transcription-of-an-interview/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can write a short summary of the nice interview, sacrificing lots of details, if that is really what you want. But, you can probably ask the video archive stuff video@ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp? They should be happy to receive your response.

Comment: I would love that. 

I will contact them, and for those who want a full transcription I will post what I receive here.

Comment: He is saying something like the following for math students. When he got stuck in his second year in U. Tokyo but not in math department, he read the van der Waerden's algebra book, got fascinated, and became crazy about math. He was influenced by Kawada-sensei on class field theories and studied under Ihara-sensei. As an advice, he thinks when you study theories in math, unlike others, your most beautiful dreams are in some cases the closest to your goals. He would like you to have many dreams and try, and though with chances of getting stuck in one day, have fun and enjoy. 

Comment: He also mentions his encounters with math in his school days, some of his famous stories in his university days, and many others.